# Change path to script files in index.html @angular-cli

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli, html-webpack-plugin

I am changing the default path to index.html to be /Views/Home/index.cshtml. As I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 to host an angular app.

The problem now is that all script file path generated in index.cshtml when running `ng build` is generating a pth like `./../wwwroot/vendor.js`.

Is there a way to change the path to point to `~\vendor.js`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to deal with --base-href build option

Comment: Thanks @dc-p8, I run the app on the root, so --base-href won't help here.